# Symfony2 configure DB storage sessions

Tags: symfony

UPDATE: problem solved, see the comments (many issues, the versions differences was but one of them).

I'm trying to configure sessions in Symfony2 in config.yml file. I have the following configuration:

```
session:
    default_locale: %locale%
    lifetime:       7200
    auto_start:     true
    storage_id:     session.storage.pdo

parameters:
  pdo.db_options:
    db_table:    session
    db_id_col:   session_id
    db_data_col: session_value
    db_time_col: session_time

services:
  pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
      - "mysql:dbname=%database_name%"
      - %database_user%
      - %database_password%

session.storage.pdo:
  class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\SessionStorage\PdoSessionStorage
  arguments: [@pdo, %session.storage.options%, %pdo.db_options%]
```

It's based on Symfony2's cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html

I've created exactly the same table as in the given link.

However, it doesn't work. I get some "blank" error (no error message, but "PDO Exception" and "Error Exception"). I admit I have no much knowledge on configuring the Symfony2 or any info (that's why I'm using cookbook). I lost a lot of time and see no much documentation about it in the internet, not mentioning the fact that internet is quite silent about this case (having session storaged to DB table in Symfony2).

My NetBeans is "shouting" sth about the last line:

```
  arguments: [@pdo, %session.storage.options%, %pdo.db_options%]
```

"ScannerException while scanning for the next token we had this found character @(64) that cannot start any token".

UPDATE:
Hmm now I'm not sure if it's about the configuration. I can see that Symfony2's cookbook (use... ) example doesn't match actually the file structure in the Symfony2's bundle. In a word, there is no such file-path, but after putting the real one it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are probably reading the wrong docs. If you downloaded v2.1, you should use this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html

Comment: Well much to say. You were right about some differnces in versions. Additionaly, some issues were connected to the newest v2.1. Some not. There are things about Symfony2 that are not quite good unfortunetely.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you with Symfony 2.5. Turns out my solution was to disable session.auto_start in php.ini. The PdoSessionStorage will not take over if the session is being started before PDO has the opportunity to take control of it. I had overlooked this at first because I was modifying the wrong one (I had two copies of php.ini). To check if this is the problem on yours, run this command:

```
echo ini_get('session.auto_start');
```

If that returns a '1' or a 'true', then be sure to set this in your php.ini:

```
session.auto_start = 0
```

So for reference, here is my setup with Symfony 2.5 to make this work:

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.pdo

parameters:
    pdo.db_options:
        db_table:    session
        db_id_col:   session_id
        db_data_col: session_value
        db_time_col: session_time

services:
    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        arguments: ["@pdo", "%pdo.db_options%"]
    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            dsn: "mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%"
            user: "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
        calls:
            - [setAttribute, [3, 2]] # \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
```